# DRYing out my Django view: Please help me!

Tags: django, django-views

I hope this is a good first question.  I've been trying to DRY out my Django code, but unfortunately I keep getting hit with several errors! (Forgive me if I don't post the code with problems - I'll just post the code that works)  I've tried using @decorators, and also putting a view within a view.  Please help me!

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404, get_list_or_404
from blog.models import Post, User, Blog, Comment
from blog.forms import CommentForm, PostForm, BlogForm
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
import datetime
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template import RequestContext
from django import forms

def limiter(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('accounts.views.login_view'))

def postindex(request):
    posts = get_list_or_404(Post.objects.all())
    return render_to_response('index.html', {'posts':posts})

def onepost(request, postid):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=postid)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('accounts.views.login_view'))
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            c = Comment(owner=request.user,
                post=Post.objects.get(pk=postid),
                time=datetime.datetime.now(),
                text=cd['text'])
            c.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blog.views.onepost', 
                args=[postid]))
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    return render_to_response('single.html',
        {'post':post,'comments':post.comment_set.all(),
        'form':form},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def userlist(request):
    users = get_list_or_404(User.objects.all())
    return render_to_response('userlist.html', {'users':users})

def bloglist(request, userid):
    blogs = get_list_or_404(Blog.objects.filter(owner__pk=userid))
    return render_to_response('bloglist.html', {'blogs':blogs})

def postlist(request, blogid):
    posts = get_list_or_404(Post.objects.filter(blog__pk=blogid))
    return render_to_response('postlist.html', {'posts':posts})

def landing(request):
    return render_to_response('landing.html', {})

def dash(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('accounts.views.login_view'))
    user = request.user
    blogs = Blog.objects.filter(owner=request.user)
    comments = Comment.objects.filter(owner=request.user)
    posts = Post.objects.filter(blog__owner=request.user)
    return render_to_response('dash.html',
        {'user':user, 'blogs':blogs, 'comments':comments, 'posts':posts})

def newpost(request, blogid):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('accounts.views.login_view'))
    blog = Blog.objects.get(pk=blogid)
    if not request.user == blog.owner:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blog.views.dash'))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            p = Post(title=cd['title'],
                blog=Blog.objects.get(pk=blogid),
                date=datetime.datetime.now(),
                content=cd['content'])
            p.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blog.views.postlist', 
                args=[blogid]))
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render_to_response('chngpost.html',
        {'blog':blog,
        'form':form},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def editpost(request, postid):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('accounts.views.login_view'))
    post = Post.objects.get(pk=postid)
    if not request.user == post.blog.owner:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blog.views.dash'))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            post.title=cd['title']
            post.content=cd['content']
            post.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blog.views.onepost', 
                args=[postid]))
    else:
        form = PostForm(initial={'title':post.title,'content':post.content})
    return render_to_response('chngpost.html',
        {'post':post,
        'form':form},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def delpost(request, postid):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('accounts.views.login_view'))
    post = Post.objects.get(pk=postid)
    if not request.user == post.blog.owner:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blog.views.dash'))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post.delete()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blog.views.dash'))
    return render_to_response('delpost.html',
        {'post':post},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def newblog(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('accounts.views.login_view'))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BlogForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            b = Blog(title=cd['title'],
                owner=request.user)
            b.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blog.views.bloglist', 
                args=[request.user.pk]))
    else:
        form = BlogForm()
    return render_to_response('chngpost.html',
        {'form':form},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def delcomment(request, commentid):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('accounts.views.login_view'))
    comment = Comment.objects.get(pk=commentid)
    if not (request.user == comment.post.blog.owner) | (request.user == comment.owner):
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blog.views.dash'))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment.delete()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blog.views.dash'))
    return render_to_response('delpost.html',
        {},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

(Hope that's formatted properly)  The code I'd like to factor out especially is

```
if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('accounts.views.login_view'))
```

But of course any more suggestions would be appreciated!  Thank you so much!
    `

Comment: Welcome to SO. +1 from me for caring about your first question :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Use `login_required` decorator ([docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/auth/#the-login-required-decorator))
2. Use modelforms for editing/creating models. ([docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/modelforms/))
3. If you need to just pass something to template, use `direct_to_template` generic view ([docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-simple-direct-to-template))

Comment: Actually, sorry, I also wanted to take out the part                  if not request.user == post.blog.owner:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blog.views.dash'))           Also, can you show me you'd recommend me to use 2 and 3?  I'm already using the both of them at parts in my code.  Thanks!

Comment: 1. If you want some more complex logic, you should write your own decorator. 2. If `CommentForm` and `PostForm` are already modelforms you should use its `save()` method. And pass the instance to the constructor if you want to edit the object. 3. For example `postlist` can be rewritten in one line: `direct_to_template(template='postlist.html', extra_context={posts: Post.objects.filter(blog__pk=blogid)})` And you can even remove this code from views and place it in the urls (click the link to docs I gave).

Comment: I'm looking for how to write my own decorators, but I'm not seeing much that I really understand...  Is there a tutorial you understand?  And thanks for the tips 2 and 3, I especially didn't know about using a ModelForm's save(). :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use **@login_required** decorator for that. You can find out more at Django documentation: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required.

Please describe any problems that you are experiencing.

Comment: Thanks!  I'd been looking for that decorator.  I don't suppose you know how I'd write my own decorators too?

Comment: just refer to this links: [sample django decorator](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/498217-custom-django-login_required-decorator/) and [understandind decorators](http://uswaretech.com/blog/2009/06/understanding-decorators/)

Comment: Thank you!  Those links help a lot!